# Swift - Jump between textfields with one button

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTzp7.png)

```
        @IBOutlet weak var umCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var doisCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cincoCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var dezCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var vinteCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cinquentaCent: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var umEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var doisEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cincoEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var dezEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var vinteEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cinquentaEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var cemEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var duzentosEuro: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var quinhentosEuro: UITextField!

        @IBAction func proximo(_ sender: UIButton) {

        }
```

I want to jump between the 15 textFields when I press the "proximo" button, for example, if I have to edit the 0.01 and I want to edit the 0.02 I just need to press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an outlet collection

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFields: [UITextFields]!
```

In Interface Builder (IB) add your text fields to the collection outlet in the appropriate order.

```
@IBAction func proximo(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    if let index = textFields.firstIndex { $0.isFirstResponder }
    {
        let nextIndex = (index + 1) % textFields.count // Wraps around back to index 0.

        textFields[nextIndex].becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Optional: Select first text field if none was selected (yet).
        textFields[0].becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error (Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField' to expected argument type 'Int') on (let nextIndex = (index + 1) % textFields.count)

Comment: @FbioCarlosHenriquesdaSilva Apologies, should have been `textFields.firstIndex` instead of `textFields.first`.  I've fixed my answer.